# No sound after suspend

Tags: drivers, sound, hp, 19.04

On a HP Laptop with Ubuntu 19.04 (dual boot with Windows 10) the internal loud speakers and headphones are working. Unfortunately only after a boot or reboot, but not after waking up the laptop from suspend.

Ubuntu recognizes the audio device after a suspend (listed in lspci) but neither loud-speakers nor headphones work. Volume can be modified but does not change anything. Do you have any idea how to force to re-load them after suspend?

`sudo lspci -v` gives:

```
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 3198 (rev 03)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 84b6
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
Memory at a1310000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at a1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

`aplay -l` gives the same output right after a reboot and waking up from suspend:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC236 Analog [ALC236 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I tried the commands suggested [here under step 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) without success.

My laptop is a 14ma0307ng.

Comment: Can you please check that the selected sound device is the same after yo suspend. Some people have reported that their device gets changed to HDMI after suspending. Please check this and report back.

Comment: Thanks for joining Askubuntu! I am not sure, but HDMI is not listed in the system-settings. The only device listed are "headphones" which are not plugged in. Furthermore, `pactl list short sinks` gives `0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz IDLE` after suspend. A reload of pulseaudio does not change the situation.

Comment: What is the exact model of your machine? Also, when you say you reloaded pulse audio, did you just take it down and back up or did you purge and re-install? Probably should also ask - are the speakers listed in settings prior to suspend?

Comment: Just to save time, in case you havent already tried this (you prob did, but just in case): "sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio &&
                     sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio"                        Then "sudo alsa force-reload"

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestions. I already tried the to reinstall pulseaudio as you described in your last comment and typing `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`. I will add the model of my machine in the question. The speakers are listed prior to suspend as `speakers -  built in audio` in the settings menu.

Comment: Was this problem ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this bug: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110916#c5

There is a workaround also until the patch hits Canonical's repositories. If you don't need hdmi audio output just drop

```
snd_hda_intel.probe_mask=0x01
```

to kernel boot params. Works for me.

Comment: The bug report is for an Asus and question is about an HP. Also bug report says to look for specific error messages. Suggest listing a couple so others know to try the fix.