# No sound after sleep - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, suspend, alsa, speakers

I have a Xioami notebook pro laptop on Ubuntu 20.04 (same issue on 18.04).

After the laptop goes in sleep/hibernate mode, there is no sound that comes out of the speakers. The system settings (settings>sounds) are detecting music is being played and the headphones are working fine after sleep. The issue is only related to the speakers integrated in the laptop. As a quick fix, I need to reboot to have the speakers to work again.

I have tried the options below without success:

1. Open alsamixer and do not see any "muted speaker"
2. Enter in the terminal: `sudo alsa force-reload`
3. Set up the script that reload alsa after sleep as indicated on the Ubuntu help page
4. `pavucontrol` is also install on my laptop
5. Tried to kill and restart pulseaudio

Let me know if you have any ideas to fix the issue.
I believe it is driver related, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

---

Please find below the information mentioned on the hardware.

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xb4214000 irq 147
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02c8]
    Subsystem: Xiaomi Device [1d72:1905]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

`pacmd list-cards`:

```
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xb4214000 irq 147"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "02c8"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please tell us about your hardware: `aplay -l`, `cat /proc/asound/cards`, `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `pacmd list-cards`

Comment: The same problem on Xiaomi. Please help!

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? I have the same one

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have a success story (thank to [Night Str](https://askubuntu.com/users/1149227/night-str))!

The same hardware. The same situation after sleep mode.
First of all get root privileges:

```
$ sudo su -
```

Than discover your devices:

```
# lspci -vvv
...
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8 (prog-if 80)
        Subsystem: Xiaomi Device 1963
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 148
        Region 0: Memory at c4214000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Region 4: Memory at c4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
...
```

So, my device id is 00:1f.3. Let`s check it:

```
# ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/ | grep 00:1f.3
0000:00:1f.3
```

Here is the trick:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/remove
# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

The first command disconnects the driver from the device and detaches the device from the tree. The driver (snd_hda_intel) is not unloaded, just disconnected.
The second command rescans pci devices.

As result, sound appears back.

Comment: this worked for me as well- thank you so much - will look at making it in a script!

Comment: here is the script, which does magic automatically: https://github.com/GHopperMSK/configs/blob/master/bin/restart-sound

Comment: says permission denied error for me..even after i do sudo su -

Comment: @abhigyannayak I had the same problem. What I did was editing these files on vim: `sudo vi /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/remove`, then add "1" to the file content and save. And then, do the same with `/sys/bus/pci/rescan`

Comment: I found the core cause.. this citrix workspace creates some issues, not sure what it does iternally.. do you also have similar software installed in your system?

Comment: permission defined even with sudo. Editing fiels also want help, newly made files a read only in memory files.

Answer (score 11):

i have same problem. And i find a solution, but it dosn't work in kde i don't known why.

Solution:

```bsh
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/<device_address>/remove
sleep 1
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

To search the device address:  `lspci | grep Audio`

**Update:**

Solution to apply commands after wakeup:

You can create new file: `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/99_restart_sound`
and insert the following source code:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
  
case "$1" in
    post)
        DEVICE_ID=`lspci -D |grep Audio|awk '{print $1}'`
        echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/${DEVICE_ID}/remove
        sleep 1
        echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
esac
```

The file must be executable:

```bsh
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/99_restart_sound
```

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), how does this answer the question when you say it didn't work.

Comment: I testing in Kde and Gnome. So it's work fine for gnome but not for kde.

Comment: I am on debian (ubuntu) and it works fine with out the "sleep 1" - trying to understand the reason for adding it

Comment: Good also looping with multiple devices https://gist.github.com/muka/d5492a25252a5edf332934201705dfe7

Answer (score 8):

type this command:

pulseaudio -k

each time your computer out of sleep.

could be related to this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1888598

Comment: Is there any alternative to killing pulseaudio? Some programs don't work through its restart.

Answer (score 2):

This command worked for me 
`amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle`

Seems it mutes then unmutes the master audio device

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out all the audio device IDs from `lspci -vvv` (please replace device id according in the below mentioned commands) :

```
sudo echo 1 |sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:03.0/remove
sudo echo 1 |sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/remove
sudo echo 1 |sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/remove
sleep 10
sudo echo 1 |sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
sleep 10
pulseaudio --kill; pulseaudio --start
```