# ACPI/Battery Monitor, LED Brightness, and Speakers All Work Intermittently

Tags: sound, acpi, 22.10, lg

My battery monitor, speakers, led control (both keyboard and monitor) all work intermittently.  When the speakers don't work pavucontrol still shows sound/changing levels and the headphone jack, bluetooth, and HDMI still do work.   The speakers seem mostly independent of the led control, but the LEDs and battery monitor consistently work or do not work together and when they aren't working `upowerd` usually runs at 100% on one core.  Also, the speakers never work after a suspend/resume.
The only relevant error I've found is in syslog

```
systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@leds:kbd_backlight.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
systemd[1]: systemd-backlight@leds:kbd_backlight.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:kbd_backlight.
```

I think I've seen a similar message for the monitor LEDs but I can't find it in the logs now.  There are also lots of ACPI errors, but it sounds like those are common and seem the same or similar between boots with working LEDs/sound and without.

For the sound I've looked at modules loaded when working and not and tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234807/no-sound-after-sleep-ubuntu-20-04) but haven't had any luck.  I also read that the display manager was causing problems with the sound for some people so I've tried lightdm and gdm but saw no difference.

The only thing that seems to fix it (at least until suspend or reboot) is booting into Windows.  I sometime have to power cycle a few times to get it to boot into Windows, then Windows does its automatic repair thing and when I reboot into Ubuntu everything works.  Sometimes just rebooting Ubuntu fixes it, but not often.

## System Information

- LG Gram 16 2 in 1, model 16T90Q-K.AAC7U1
- OSes: Ubuntu 22.10 with Plasma Desktop and Windows 11
- Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)

Since it works intermittently I don't think it is a problem with drivers or hardware but if more specifics would be helpful I can provide whatever information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the ACPI/Battery Monitor and LED control (screen and keyboard).  I disabled firmware updates by removing `fwupd` and that seems to  have fixed it.  When I boot into Windows it does "repairs" but my LED control and battery monitor haven't stopped working in several weeks.  I'm still working on the speakers.